# EC2 instance memory and VCPU count with CDK

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cdk

Is there a way to get memory size and VCPU count with CDK? The use case is that my application (a presto cluster deployed in EMR) uses some memory configurations that are based on the memory size and VCPU count, for example:

```
{
                classification: 'presto-config',
                configurationProperties: {
                    'query.max-memory-per-node': `${instanceMemory * 0.15}GB`, // 25% of a node
                    'query.max-total-memory-per-node': `${instanceMemory * 0.5}GB`, // 50% of a node
                    'query.max-memory': `${instanceMemory * 0.5 * coreInstanceGroupNodeCount}GB`, // 50% of the cluster
                    'query.max-total-memory': `${instanceMemory * 0.8 * coreInstanceGroupNodeCount}GB`, // 80% of the cluster
                    'task.concurrency': vcpuCount.toString(),
                    'task.max-worker-threads': (vcpuCount * 4).toString(),
                },
            },
```

The fleet running the build stage of my pipeline has to remain network jailed, so I can't use something like this:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instance-types.html

Does CDK have this anywhere in some sort of way so that i don't have to hard code the values or make any http requests?

Comment: Did the answer help?

Answer (score 2):

You can get this information from the AWS API using a Custom Resource. Here's an example in Python:

```python
from aws_cdk import (
    aws_ec2 as ec2,
    custom_resources as cr,
)
from constructs import Construct

class InstanceTypeInfo(Construct):
    def __init__(
        self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, instance_type: ec2.InstanceType
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id)
        self.info_provider = cr.AwsCustomResource(
            self,
            "Default",
            policy=cr.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.from_sdk_calls(resources=["*"]),
            on_update=cr.AwsSdkCall(
                service="EC2",
                action="describeInstanceTypes",
                parameters={"InstanceTypes": [instance_type.to_string()]},
                output_paths=["InstanceTypes.0"],
                physical_resource_id=cr.PhysicalResourceId.of(self.node.path),
            ),
        )

    @property
    def vcpu(self) -> int:
        return int(
            cdk.Token.as_number(
                self.info_provider.get_response_field_reference(
                    "InstanceTypes.0.VCpuInfo.DefaultVCpus"
                )
            )
        )

    @property
    def memory_mib(self) -> int:
        return int(
            cdk.Token.as_number(
                self.info_provider.get_response_field_reference(
                    "InstanceTypes.0.MemoryInfo.SizeInMiB"
                )
            )
        )
```

Usage:

```python
my_instance_type = ec2.InstanceType.of(
    instance_class=ec2.InstanceClass.T3,
    instance_size=ec2.InstanceSize.MEDIUM
)

instance_info = InstanceTypeInfo(self, "instance_info", instance_type=my_instance_type)

vcpu = instance_info.vcpu
```

You cannot perform arithmetic operations on the outputs, though, as they're resolved during deployment (after you CDK code has generated the CloudFormation template).

To do that, you'd need another lambda-backed custom resource that would do the math operations you need and return the result as a token.